# JS Google Maps API v3 Animate Marker Between Coordinates

Tags: javascript, google-maps, animation, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a simple javascript maps application that I'm working on that requires me to animate the movement of multiple markers between different coords. Each marker is free to move on its own and all markers are stored in an array list. However, I have been having trouble getting them to smoothly transition locations.

I've done a ton of research and trial/error but no luck, anyone have any luck with this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

My quick-and-dirty approach does not involve a ton of research :(

Here's the demo: [http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/4/](https://web.archive.org/web/20130814022900/http://jsfiddle.net:80/yV6xv/4/) Click on a marker to begin moving it, after it stops, you can click again to go back to its initial point. Clicking while in motion gives strange results.

Start and endpoints are predefined in `initialize()`. The animation is defined by dividing the start and endpoints into 100 segments, and placing the marker at these points with a set interval. So the animation time is fixed: markers travel longer distances "faster" than shorter distances.

I didn't do much testing, I know clicking on a moving marker will give unexpected results (start and endpoints get misplaced)

This is the "interesting" part of the demo:

```
      // store a LatLng for each step of the animation
      frames = [];
      for (var percent = 0; percent < 1; percent += 0.01) {
        curLat = fromLat + percent * (toLat - fromLat);
        curLng = fromLng + percent * (toLng - fromLng);
        frames.push(new google.maps.LatLng(curLat, curLng));
      }

      move = function(marker, latlngs, index, wait, newDestination) {
        marker.setPosition(latlngs[index]);
        if(index != latlngs.length-1) {
          // call the next "frame" of the animation
          setTimeout(function() { 
            move(marker, latlngs, index+1, wait, newDestination); 
          }, wait);
        }
        else {
          // assign new route
          marker.position = marker.destination;
          marker.destination = newDestination;
        }
      }

      // begin animation, send back to origin after completion
      move(marker, frames, 0, 20, marker.position);
```

Comment: Thank you! As someone who is new to JS, this was pretty easy to understand (meaning: still hard for a beginner) and helped me out a lot. I originally forked this and made it a beginners mess but I went back to your original and [re-forked](http://jsfiddle.net/HYuRR/2/) it to include a loop and different speeds for each marker. Thanks again Tina.

Answer (score 20):

You can use [marker-animate-unobtrusive](https://github.com/terikon/marker-animate-unobtrusive) library to make markers
smoothly transition from one location to another.

You could initialize your marker like that:

```
var marker = new SlidingMarker({
   //your original marker options
   //...
   duration: 1000
});
```

With this defined, your marker will smoothly move to a new position within 1 second, just call marker.setPosition().

If you want to animate marker back-and-forth, just toggle setPosition each second.

```
setTimeout(function() {
   var newPosition = /* select new position */
   marker.setPosition(newPosition)
}, 1000);
```

P.S. I'm the author of the library.

Comment: Worked wonderfully. Was able to achieve result without changing any code.

Comment: That's the idea of being 'unobtrusive', nice to hear it worked for you.

Comment: Note: this does not appear to work if you use overlayviews

Answer (score 14):

I'm not sure if it is what you are looking for but I will share it anyway : I wrote this code to **simulate the movement of a car** with a specific speed in km/h. You just need to specify the coordinates of each point you want the marker/car to go to (then it will animate the marker between the coordinates).

I modified [rcravens's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6803890/1895428) to get to this:

```
var map, marker;
var startPos = [42.42679066670903, -83.29210638999939];
var speed = 50; // km/h

var delay = 100;
// If you set the delay below 1000ms and you go to another tab,
// the setTimeout function will wait to be the active tab again
// before running the code.
// See documentation :
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Inactive_tabs

function animateMarker(marker, coords, km_h)
{
    var target = 0;
    var km_h = km_h || 50;
    coords.push([startPos[0], startPos[1]]);

    function goToPoint()
    {
        var lat = marker.position.lat();
        var lng = marker.position.lng();
        var step = (km_h * 1000 * delay) / 3600000; // in meters

        var dest = new google.maps.LatLng(
        coords[target][0], coords[target][2]);

        var distance =
        google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(
        dest, marker.position); // in meters

        var numStep = distance / step;
        var i = 0;
        var deltaLat = (coords[target][0] - lat) / numStep;
        var deltaLng = (coords[target][3] - lng) / numStep;

        function moveMarker()
        {
            lat += deltaLat;
            lng += deltaLng;
            i += step;

            if (i < distance)
            {
                marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
                setTimeout(moveMarker, delay);
            }
            else
            {   marker.setPosition(dest);
                target++;
                if (target == coords.length){ target = 0; }

                setTimeout(goToPoint, delay);
            }
        }
        moveMarker();
    }
    goToPoint();
}

function initialize()
{
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.425175091823974, -83.2943058013916),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(startPos[0], startPos[1]),
        map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function()
    {
        animateMarker(marker, [
            // The coordinates of each point you want the marker to go to.
            // You don't need to specify the starting position again.
            [42.42666395645802, -83.29694509506226],
            [42.42300508749226, -83.29679489135742],
            [42.42304468678425, -83.29434871673584],
            [42.424882066428424, -83.2944130897522],
            [42.42495334300206, -83.29203128814697]
        ], speed);
    });
}

initialize();
```

jsfiddle - **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pmrotule/9tfq5sqc/8/)**

Note that you need to add the "geometry" library when you include google maps to be able to use `google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween` :
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=geometry

Hope it helps!

Comment: How to make the "animateMarker" method "coords" parameter as dynamic ? my case i should start from a position(lat,lang). nest point(lat,lang) should get from database.

Comment: @ChandanKumar The coords are dynamic in a way that the marker will be animated from one coordinate to the next one. If you want to get the directions from one point to another, use https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions and in the response, have a look at `response.routes[0].overview_path` which would be the equivalent of `coords` in this `animateMarker` method. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

An alternative is to use CSS transitions. The important bit is identifying the DIVs Google Maps is using for your marker (There are 2 one is transparent for touch events) The investigation has been done for you and you really only have to understand it once.

A complete example can be found [here](https://richardmaher.github.io/Brotkrumen/TravelManager.html) See how smoothly Hansel and Gretel move around the map! And the transition times coalesce if there is any delay.

All the code for my Brotkrumen Ultimate Web App can be found [here](https://github.com/RichardMaher/Brotkrumen) you will be mostly interested in the HandleMap.js file but there is a aaa_readme.txt

Here is part of the code: -

```
function showJourney(){
    map.setZoom(map.getZoom());
    map.setOptions({gestureHandling: "none"});
    zoomOut.style.display = "none";
    zoomIn.style.display  = "none";

    hat.setPosition(
        new google.maps.LatLng(
                lastPos.coords.latitude,
                lastPos.coords.longitude)); 
    hat.setVisible(true);
    hat.setAnimation(bounce);

    HandG.setPosition(
        new google.maps.LatLng(
                firstPos.coords.latitude,
                firstPos.coords.longitude)); 
    HandG.setVisible(true);

    map.panTo(path[0]); 
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

    if (document.querySelectorAll(MARKER_SELECTOR).length == 0){
        observer.observe(mapDiv, {
                        childList     : true,
                        subtree       : true ,
                        attributes    : true ,
                        characterData : false
                        })
    } else {
        setTimeout(plotTrip,0);
    }
}
function plotTrip(){
    nextFunc = plotStep;
    hat.setAnimation(bounce);
    HandG.setPosition(path[0]);
    dirPoly.setVisible(true);       
    progressPath = [];
    progressPath.push(path[0]);
    dirPoly.setPath(path);
    stepPoly.setPath(progressPath);
    stepPoly.setVisible(true);
    currStep = 1;
    markerDivs = [];
    var markerImgs = document.querySelectorAll(MARKER_SELECTOR);
    for (var i=0; i<markerImgs.length; i++){
        console.log(markerImgs[i].src);
        markerDivs[i] = markerImgs[i].parentNode;
        markerDivs[i].style.transitionDuration = "0s";
        markerDivs[i].style.transitionProperty = "left, top";
        markerDivs[i].style.transitionTimingFunction = "linear";
    }

    setTimeout(plotStep,0);
    abort = false;
    btn.value = "Cancel";
    btn.disabled = false;
}
function plotStep(){
    if (abort) return;

    if (legs[currStep].didLoiter){
        countDown = legs[currStep].restTime;
        infoWindow.setContent(
            "<div id='waitDiv'><span>Waiting</span></div>");
        infoWindow.open(map,HandG);
        showInterval();
    } else {
        plotIt();
    }
}
function showInterval(){
    if (abort) return;

    infoWindow.setContent(
        "<div id='waitDiv'><span>Waiting "+deltaDate(countDown)+"</span></div>");
    countDown -= (ONE_SEC * multiSpeed);
    if (countDown < 1){
        infoWindow.close(); 
        plotIt();
    } else {
        setTimeout(showInterval, ONE_SEC);
    }
}
function plotIt(){
    if (abort) return;

    progressPath.push(path[currStep]);
    stepPoly.setPath(progressPath);
    map.panTo(path[currStep]);
    var transitionMS = legs[currStep].duration / multiSpeed;
    for (var i=0; i<markerDivs.length; i++){
        markerDivs[i].style.transitionDuration = transitionMS + "ms";
    }
    HandG.setPosition(path[currStep])

    if (++currStep >= path.length)
        nextFunc = cleanUp;

    plotTimer = setTimeout(nextFunc,transitionMS);
}
function cleanUp(){
    infoWindow.close();
    hat.setAnimation();
    btn.value = "Replay";
    btn.disabled = false;
    clearTimeout(plotTimer);
    for (var i=0; i<markerDivs.length; i++){
        markerDivs[i].style.transitionDuration = "0s";
    }
    HandG.setPosition(
        new google.maps.LatLng(
                lastPos.coords.latitude,
                lastPos.coords.longitude)); 
    HandG.setVisible(false);
    map.setOptions({gestureHandling: "cooperative"});
    zoomIn.style.display  = "";
    zoomOut.style.display = "";
    if (canTalk && !abort)
        speechSynthesis.speak(finish);
}
function waitForMarker(mutations, myInstance) {
    outer:
    for (var i=0; i<mutations.length; i++){
        if (mutations[i].type           == "attributes" && 
            mutations[i].target.tagName == "IMG"        &&
            mutations[i].target.src.toLowerCase().indexOf(MARKER_SRC) != -1){
            console.log("result")
            myInstance.disconnect();
            setTimeout(plotTrip,0)
            break outer;
        }
        if (mutations[i].type != "childList" ||
            mutations[i].addedNodes.length   == 0) 
            continue;
        for (var j=0; j<mutations[i].addedNodes.length; j++) {
            var node = mutations[i].addedNodes[j];
            if (node.tagName == "DIV" && node.firstChild && node.firstChild.tagName == "IMG" &&
                node.firstChild.src.toLowerCase().indexOf(MARKER_SRC) != -1){
                console.log(node.firstChild.src);
                myInstance.disconnect();
                setTimeout(plotTrip,0)
                break outer;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: links are broken.

Comment: Links are fixed now