# How to make smooth marker movement using Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

My marker jerks too sharply when it instantly changes its position. Is there any equivalent of a CSS `transiton: 1s linear` in Google Maps API so that my marker can move smoothly?
Here is my map init code:

```js
var marker;

    function initMap() {
    // Map initialization
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 1,
            center: { lat: 59.325, lng: 18.070 }
        });
    // Marker settings
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            draggable: true,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            position: { lat: 59.327, lng: 18.067 }
        });
    // Marker moves every second
        setInterval( () => {
            moveMarker();
        }, 1000);    
    }

    var a = 1;
    function moveMarker() {
        marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(a++, a++));
    }
```

```css
#map {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCJYSNYPAfcm8ZV4pi8nj6fbeOtbQQpr7Y&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS Google Maps API v3 Animate Marker Between Coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904476/js-google-maps-api-v3-animate-marker-between-coordinates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very doable but takes work. The important bit is identifying the DIVs Google Maps is using for your marker (There are 2 one is transparent for touch events) The investigation has been done for you and you really only have to understand it once.

A complete example can be found [here](https://hypocampus.applications.uwa.edu.au/travelmanager.html) See how smoothly Hansel and Gretel move around the map! And the transition times coalesce if there is any delay.

All the code for my Brotkrumen Ultimate Web App can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7Rmd3Rn8_hDNW1zSWRoXzBTclU) you will be mostly interested in the HandleMap.js file but there is a aaa_readme.txt

Here is part of the code: -

```
function showJourney(){
    map.setZoom(map.getZoom());
    map.setOptions({gestureHandling: "none"});
    zoomOut.style.display = "none";
    zoomIn.style.display  = "none";

    hat.setPosition(
        new google.maps.LatLng(
                lastPos.coords.latitude,
                lastPos.coords.longitude)); 
    hat.setVisible(true);
    hat.setAnimation(bounce);

    HandG.setPosition(
        new google.maps.LatLng(
                firstPos.coords.latitude,
                firstPos.coords.longitude)); 
    HandG.setVisible(true);

    map.panTo(path[0]); 
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

    if (document.querySelectorAll(MARKER_SELECTOR).length == 0){
        observer.observe(mapDiv, {
                        childList     : true,
                        subtree       : true ,
                        attributes    : true ,
                        characterData : false
                        })
    } else {
        setTimeout(plotTrip,0);
    }
}
function plotTrip(){
    nextFunc = plotStep;
    hat.setAnimation(bounce);
    HandG.setPosition(path[0]);
    dirPoly.setVisible(true);       
    progressPath = [];
    progressPath.push(path[0]);
    dirPoly.setPath(path);
    stepPoly.setPath(progressPath);
    stepPoly.setVisible(true);
    currStep = 1;
    markerDivs = [];
    var markerImgs = document.querySelectorAll(MARKER_SELECTOR);
    for (var i=0; i<markerImgs.length; i++){
        console.log(markerImgs[i].src);
        markerDivs[i] = markerImgs[i].parentNode;
        markerDivs[i].style.transitionDuration = "0s";
        markerDivs[i].style.transitionProperty = "left, top";
        markerDivs[i].style.transitionTimingFunction = "linear";
    }

    setTimeout(plotStep,0);
    abort = false;
    btn.value = "Cancel";
    btn.disabled = false;
}
function plotStep(){
    if (abort) return;

    if (legs[currStep].didLoiter){
        countDown = legs[currStep].restTime;
        infoWindow.setContent(
            "<div id='waitDiv'><span>Waiting</span></div>");
        infoWindow.open(map,HandG);
        showInterval();
    } else {
        plotIt();
    }
}
function showInterval(){
    if (abort) return;

    infoWindow.setContent(
        "<div id='waitDiv'><span>Waiting "+deltaDate(countDown)+"</span></div>");
    countDown -= (ONE_SEC * multiSpeed);
    if (countDown < 1){
        infoWindow.close(); 
        plotIt();
    } else {
        setTimeout(showInterval, ONE_SEC);
    }
}
function plotIt(){
    if (abort) return;

    progressPath.push(path[currStep]);
    stepPoly.setPath(progressPath);
    map.panTo(path[currStep]);
    var transitionMS = legs[currStep].duration / multiSpeed;
    for (var i=0; i<markerDivs.length; i++){
        markerDivs[i].style.transitionDuration = transitionMS + "ms";
    }
    HandG.setPosition(path[currStep])

    if (++currStep >= path.length)
        nextFunc = cleanUp;

    plotTimer = setTimeout(nextFunc,transitionMS);
}
function cleanUp(){
    infoWindow.close();
    hat.setAnimation();
    btn.value = "Replay";
    btn.disabled = false;
    clearTimeout(plotTimer);
    for (var i=0; i<markerDivs.length; i++){
        markerDivs[i].style.transitionDuration = "0s";
    }
    HandG.setPosition(
        new google.maps.LatLng(
                lastPos.coords.latitude,
                lastPos.coords.longitude)); 
    HandG.setVisible(false);
    map.setOptions({gestureHandling: "cooperative"});
    zoomIn.style.display  = "";
    zoomOut.style.display = "";
    if (canTalk && !abort)
        speechSynthesis.speak(finish);
}
function waitForMarker(mutations, myInstance) {
    outer:
    for (var i=0; i<mutations.length; i++){
        if (mutations[i].type           == "attributes" && 
            mutations[i].target.tagName == "IMG"        &&
            mutations[i].target.src.toLowerCase().indexOf(MARKER_SRC) != -1){
            console.log("result")
            myInstance.disconnect();
            setTimeout(plotTrip,0)
            break outer;
        }
        if (mutations[i].type != "childList" ||
            mutations[i].addedNodes.length   == 0) 
            continue;
        for (var j=0; j<mutations[i].addedNodes.length; j++) {
            var node = mutations[i].addedNodes[j];
            if (node.tagName == "DIV" && node.firstChild && node.firstChild.tagName == "IMG" &&
                node.firstChild.src.toLowerCase().indexOf(MARKER_SRC) != -1){
                console.log(node.firstChild.src);
                myInstance.disconnect();
                setTimeout(plotTrip,0)
                break outer;
            }
        }
    }
}
```