# How can I rotate marker with smooth animation in ionic 3?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, ionic3

How can I rotate marker with animation in Google Map? Following is the my code snippet. I am using [ionic native google map](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native-google-maps) plugin.

```
moveMarker() {
let prevLat = new LatLng(this.prevPosition[0], this.prevPosition[1]);
this.prevPosition[0] += this.deltaLat;
this.prevPosition[1] += this.deltaLng;
let latlng = new LatLng(this.prevPosition[0], this.prevPosition[1]);
let heading = Spherical.computeHeading(prevLat, latlng);
this.marker.setRotation(heading);
this.marker.setPosition(latlng);

if (this.i != this.numDeltas) {
  this.i++;
  setTimeout(this.moveMarker(), this.delay);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904476/js-google-maps-api-v3-animate-marker-between-coordinates) might helps you.

Moving markers smoothly by dividing the distance into chunks