how to make the react native map camera animated with the movement of the marker but must be at the same time
how to make the react native map camera animated with the movement of the marker but must be at the same time
i use react-native-maps with google maps onn android
and i eant the camera map animated withe the marker moves at the same time
buut alwways the marker moves then the map follow so there is a delay between the map and marker also i want the marker to bhe on the buttom of the screen always
animate_point for animate the camera using clous coordinate and animate_point_GPS using gps coordinate
this is the Map Component

export default function MapUI() {
  const { authData } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const { gpsStatus, setGPSStatus } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const { mapLayer, setMapLayer } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const { positiveRCM, setPositiveRCM } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const [token, setToken] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [coordinate, setCoordinate] = useState(null);
  const mapRef = useRef(null);
  const [markersMeasurement, setMarkersMeasurement] = useState([]);
  const [prevDirection, setPrevDirection] = useState(null); // State to store previous direction

  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const { height } = Dimensions.get("window");

  /**
   * connectWebSocketApi
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    connectWebSocketApi(authData.ClientPrefix);
  }, []);

  // WebSocket event handler
  const onMessage = (event) => {
    try {
      const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
      if (data.type === "coordinate" && data.device == authData.DeviceID) {
        // Update coordinate state with the received data
        if (!gpsStatus) {
          Updatecoordinate(
            data?.latitude,
            data?.longitude,
            data?.azimuth,
            data?.speed
          );
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error parsing WebSocket data:", error);
    }
  };
  /**
   * control the permission
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    setToken(authData.TOKEN);
    setGPSStatus(gpsStatus);
    setMapLayer(mapLayer);
    setPositiveRCM(positiveRCM);
  }, []);

  /**
   * control the switch between GPS and  cloud
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    // Wait for a short delay before checking gpsStatus
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      if (gpsStatus) {
        getLocation(); //getLocation()
      } else {
        getCoordinates();
      }
    }, 500); // Adjust the delay time as needed

    // Clean up the timeout to avoid memory leaks
    return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  }, [gpsStatus]);

  /**
   * control the switch between GPS and cloud
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    if (gpsStatus) {
      const intervalId = setInterval(async () => {
        try {
          const location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({
            accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Highest,
          });

          Updatecoordinate_GPS(
            location.coords?.latitude,
            location.coords?.longitude,
            location.coords?.heading,
            location.coords?.speed
          );
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error getting location:", error);
        }
      }, 800); // Update location every 1 second

      return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
  }, []);

  /**
   *
   * @param {*} latitude
   * @param {*} longitude
   * @param {*} azimuth
   */
  const Updatecoordinate_GPS = (latitude, longitude, azimuth, speed) => {
    if (
      latitude != coordinate?.latitude ||
      longitude != coordinate?.longitude
    ) {
      const newCoordinate = {
        latitude,
        longitude,
        azimuth,
        speed,
      };
      //console.log(newCoordinate)
      setCoordinate(newCoordinate);
      animate_point_GPS(newCoordinate);
    }
  };

  /**
   *
   */
  const animate_point_GPS = async (newCoordinate) => {
    let duration = 0;
    const heading = newCoordinate?.azimuth;
    const headingChanged = Math.abs(heading - prevDirection) > 10; // Define a threshold for significant change
    headingChanged && setPrevDirection(heading); // Update previous direction

    if (newCoordinate?.speed > 100) {
      duration = 1100;
    } else if (newCoordinate?.speed > 50) {
      duration = 900;
    } else {
      duration = 1100;
    }
    // Animate camera to the new coordinates
    mapRef?.current?.animateCamera(
      {
        heading: headingChanged ? heading : prevDirection,
        center: {
          latitude: newCoordinate.latitude,
          longitude: newCoordinate.longitude,
        },

        pitch: 55,
      },
      { duration: duration }
    );
  };

  /**
   * get current location using GPS
   */
  const getLocation = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
    if (status !== "granted") {
      console.error("Permission to access location was denied");
      return;
    }

    let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({
      accuracy: Location.Accuracy.High,
    });
    const newCoordinate = {
      latitude: location.coords.latitude,
      longitude: location.coords.longitude,
      azimuth: location.coords.heading,
    };

    setCoordinate(newCoordinate);
    //console.log("location: ", location.coords)

    setLoading(false);
  };
  /**
   * get current location using 
   */

  /**
 * 
 * @param {number} latitude 
 * @param {number} longitude import defaultPin from "/default.png"

 * @param {number} azimuth 
 */
  const Updatecoordinate = (latitude, longitude, azimuth, speed) => {
    const newCoordinate = {
      latitude,
      longitude,
    };
    setCoordinate(newCoordinate);
    animate_point();
  };
  /**
   * animate_point the camera to follow the device
   */
  const animate_point = async () => {
    let duration = 0;
    const heading = gpsStatus ? coordinate?.heading : coordinate?.azimuth;
    const headingThreshold = 10; // Define a threshold for significant heading changes

    // Determine if the heading change is significant
    const headingChanged =
      prevDirection === null ||
      Math.abs(heading - prevDirection) > headingThreshold;

    if (headingChanged) {
      setPrevDirection(heading); // Update previous direction only if change is significant
    }

    if (coordinate?.speed > 100) {
      duration = 1100;
    } else if (coordinate?.speed > 50) {
      duration = 900;
    } else {
      duration = 1100;
    }

    mapRef?.current?.animateCamera(
      {
        // heading: headingChanged ? heading : prevDirection,
        center: {
          latitude: coordinate.latitude,
          longitude: coordinate.longitude,
        },
        pitch: 55,
      },
      { duration: duration }
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles_map.container}>
        {/* WebSocket configuration component */}
        <WebSocketConfig onMessage={onMessage} />

        {coordinate && (
          <>
            <MapView
              ref={mapRef}
              provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
              style={{ ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject }}
              initialRegion={{
                latitude: coordinate?.latitude,
                longitude: coordinate?.longitude,
                latitudeDelta: 0.001,
                longitudeDelta: 0.001,
              }}
            
              mapPadding={{ top: height * 0.9, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 }}
              rotateEnabled={false}
              zoomEnabled={false}
              zoomTapEnabled={false}
              zoomControlEnabled={false}
              toolbarEnabled={false}
              showsCompass={false}
              mapType={mapLayer}
            >              

              <DeviceMarker
                key={coordinate?.device}
                coord={coordinate}
                gpsStatus={gpsStatus}
                mapRef={mapRef}
              />
            </MapView>
          </>
        )}
        <View>


        </View>
        <View style={styles_map.buttonContainer}>
        
        </View>
      </View>
    </>
  );
}


and this is DeviceMarker component

export default function DeviceMarker({ coord, gpsStatus, mapRef }) {
  const [marker, setMarker] = useState(null);
  const markerRef = useRef(null);
  const duration = 1100;
  const [tracksViewChanges, setTracksViewChanges] = useState(true);

  const [coordinate, setCoordinate] = useState(
    new AnimatedRegion({
      latitude: coord?.latitude || 0, // Ensure default value is provided
      longitude: coord?.longitude || 0, // Ensure default value is provided
      latitudeDelta: 0.001,
      longitudeDelta: 0.001,
    })
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setTracksViewChanges(false);
      detectHeadingAtFirstLoad();
    }, 1000); // Adjust the delay as necessary

    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Update marker position when coord changes
    if (markerRef.current) {
      const newCoordinate = {
        latitude: coord?.latitude || 0, // Ensure default value is provided
        longitude: coord?.longitude || 0, // Ensure default value is provided
        latitudeDelta: 0.001,
        longitudeDelta: 0.001,
      };

      coordinate
        .timing({
          ...newCoordinate,
          duration,
          easing: Easing.linear,
          useNativeDriver: false,

        })
        .start();
    }
  }, [coord]);

  /**
   * detectHeadingAtFirstLoad
   */
  const detectHeadingAtFirstLoad = async () => {
    const heading = gpsStatus ? coord?.heading : coord?.azimuth;
    mapRef?.current?.animateCamera({
      heading: heading,
      center: {
        latitude: coord.latitude,
        longitude: coord.longitude,
      },
      pitch: 55,
    });
  };
  return (
    <Marker.Animated
      ref={markerRef}
      tracksViewChanges={tracksViewChanges}
      tracksInfoWindowChanges={false}
      coordinate={coordinate}
      anchor={{ x: 0.5, y: 0.5 }}
    >
      <Image
        style={{
          height: 50,
          width: 50,
          transform: [
            {
              rotate: "0deg",
            },
          ],
        }}
        source={require("../assets/icon.png")}
        resizeMode="cover"
      />
    </Marker.Animated>
  );
}


please help me to figure this out
Thank you

The only built in method that the API has is "Animating camera to a point" but there's none for the "animating of markers to a point".

Because i have new coordinates comes from api every 1 second and i want to make the marker and the camera for the map moves together at the same momement how can i do that ? Thank you

As I mentioned, there's no built in way for you to animate the camera, so you could either create some kind of method that interpolates between the distance of your next position to animate it or find some library that does so. I did a little bit of searching and found this: https://github.com/terikon/marker-animate-unobtrusive
It came from this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904476/js-google-maps-api-v3-animate-marker-between-coordinates
I'm not sure if it would work for react-native. But you can try reverse engineering the library
